# Rails Brakeman: SQL Injection for Arel

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-injection, ransack, brakeman

I have the following code in my `user_ransaker.rb` file:

```
ransacker :new_donors do
      sql = %{(
              users.id IN (
                #{User.new_donor_sql}
              )
            )}
      Arel.sql(sql)
    end
```

On `user.rb` model:

```
def self.new_donor_sql
    part_1 = %{(
      SELECT distinct(user_id)
      FROM donations
    }
    part_1
end
```

I get the following Brakeman warning for above statement:

```
Confidence: High
Category: SQL Injection
Check: SQL
Message: Possible SQL injection
Code: Arel.sql("(\n users.id IN (\n #{User.new_donor_sql}\n)\n)")
File: app/models/concerns/user_ransackers.rb
```

Is this a valid error? If I used ActiveRecord to write the SQL statement, I could have used `?` placeholder if I needed to interpolate values.  I am not really sure how to fix this warning. If this is a valid warning, how do I remediate it?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using Arel for this query? This _could_ be accomplished with ActiveRecord.

Comment: I am using Ransack gem. I am doing something similar to point #2.2 as mentioned on doc: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers. I get `undefined method 'eq' for ....` if I use ActiveRecord

Answer (score 1):

If you gonna Arel then do some relational algebra:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.new_donor_sql
    arel_table.project(arel_table[:user_id]).distinct
  end
end
```

```
ransacker :new_donors do
  User.arel_table.then do |users|
    users.where(users[:id].in(User.new_donor_sql)).where_sql
  end
end
```

You could also just drop the class method:

```
ransacker :new_donors do
  User.arel_table.then do |users|
    subquery = users.project(users[:user_id]).distinct
    users.where(users[:id].in(subquery)).where_sql
  end
end
```

Comment: I get `undefined method then for #<Arel::Table`

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? `Object#then` was introduced in 2.6 as an alias for `Object#yield_self` - older versions are EOL. If you really have to use an older version for a legacy app then  assign a variable instead `users = User.arel_table; subquery = users.project(users[:user_id]).distinct; users.where(users[:id].in(subquery)).where_sql`